# LinkedIn: "You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.", AGAIN

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I've just setup a new app in LinkedIn Developer Network and in **Other > JavaScript API Domains** text box I have only entry `http://localhost`
And still I'm getting this error when I go to the page referencing LinkedIn JavaScript (`http://localhost/linkedin/#/login`). 
The page's LinkedIn related snippet is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    //here goes the api key, and the callback function
    api_key: My_API_Key
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem with localhost. But, when I make a site in IIS, give it a valid domain name in IIS and use the same domain in "Other > JavaScript API Domains", the problem is resolved.

My domain in IIS had port 80 and the name was local.lc.com. To make it work on port 80, you would need to register the domain in Drivers>etc>hosts

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace the api_key with the client id of your linked in app.

Comment: Can you extend your answer, why this would solve the issue?